# Are Bastion's "Equip Weapon <#>" controls non-functional?

Tags: overwatch

Bastion's hero information in Overwatch shows that the <kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>2</kbd> keys switch to the sentry and recon configuration, respectively. However, pressing the keys does nothing in-game. Is this a mistake in the hero information or is my game malfunctioning?

[image: Bastion Abilities]

Comment: Those just indicate two different firing options, shift changes between his configurations to get those two modes.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the <kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>2</kbd> are a mistake. Pressing <kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>2</kbd> will never switch Bastion's weapon.

Bastion can only use one weapon in each of his configurations. There is no way to switch weapons except to change configuration.

You can find out how to change configuration a bit to the right of the screenshot in your post, according to your keybindings.

Comment: Considering that OW allows custom keybindings, I would would change "will *never* switch" to "will not switch".